# How to ignore rows where blank values excist Pandas Python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

What i'm trying to do is query a Panda DataFrame in order to give me a filtered version of the original one

```
self.waferInfo = pd.read_csv(fileName, index_col= None, na_values=['NA', ""] , usecols=[18,5,6,8,2])

print(self.waferInfo.head(5))

self.df2 = self.waferInfo[(self.waferInfo.FILE_FINISH_TS >= dateBegin) & (self.waferInfo.FILE_FINISH_TS <= dateEnd) ]

print(self.df2.head(5))
```

when the first print happens the expected rows print out but when the 2nd one is called, it appears empty. I figured out the reason that was happening was because the original DataFrame has some blanks 
for example :

```
18 5 6 8 2
A  B C   E
D  E T Y P
F  R B A L
```

I would want my Dataframe to return

```
18 5 6 8 2
D  E T Y P
F  R B A L
```

the fact that Column 8 has an empty cell it returns a complete empty DataFrame. I know this because I deleted all the rows that had empty cell's in excel and the DataFrame worked fine after that. 
is there any way to ignore rows that have a missing value.

Comment: Can you please do a better job of providing a [mcve]? Maybe, 5-10 rows of your data with expected output? Thanks.

Comment: Short answer: yes; use `df.dropna(how="any")`. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html

Comment: I went ahead and edited the question to make it a little clearer but I tried that @Evan and the 2nd appears empty

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that your assumptions about the root cause of the problem are correct. See below.

```
"""
18 5 6 8 2
A  B C   E
D  E T Y P
F  R B A L
"""
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_clipboard()
print(df)
print("\n")
print(df.dropna())
```

Output:

```
  18  5  6  8     2
0  A  B  C  E  None
1  D  E  T  Y     P
2  F  R  B  A     L


  18  5  6  8  2
1  D  E  T  Y  P
2  F  R  B  A  L
```

If `df2.head(5)` returns nothing, then it's because `df2` is empty, which is not because there are NaN's in your df.

Perhaps

```
self.waferInfo[(self.waferInfo.FILE_FINISH_TS >= dateBegin) & \
(self.waferInfo.FILE_FINISH_TS <= dateEnd) ]
```

should be

```
self.waferInfo.loc[(self.waferInfo.FILE_FINISH_TS >= dateBegin) & \
(self.waferInfo.FILE_FINISH_TS <= dateEnd) ]
```

I can't say for sure because you haven't provided enough sample data.

Comment: the ".loc" didn't change anything but all I did was use the line "dropna(inplace= True)" and that helped fix the issue