# panda query not returning correct DataFrame Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have one frame that stores the info. that I need. I then query that DataFrame to create another dataframe (`self.df2`) but this time return  the info in between `dateBegin` and `dateEnd` but is instead returning info from other times.

For example:
if I set the begin date to 11/03/18  14:40:17 and the end date to 12/06/18  14:40:17 it'll return info from 11/01/18 im not sure why it's not working.
One weird thing is, when I change `pd.read.csv` to `pd.read.excel` it works perfectly. Any idea on what I may be missing here ?

```
    self.Info = pd.read_csv(fileName, index_col= None, na_values=['NA', "" , "NaN", "nan"] , usecols=[5,6,8,18,2])
    self.Info.dropna(inplace= True)
    print(self.Info.head(5))
    self.df2 = self.Info[(self.Info.FILE_FINISH_TS >= dateBegin) & (self.Info.FILE_FINISH_TS <= dateEnd) ]
    print(self.df2.head(5))
```

Comment: Is this the same, or related to, this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53640476/how-to-ignore-rows-where-blank-values-excist-pandas-python

Comment: well different. im not sure what could be wrong here. this one is questioning the query but its still weird that it works for excel and not for csv

Comment: And what was the result of the answer I prepared for you yesterday?

Comment: just responded to that one now

Comment: Maybe read_csv is parsing the datetimes differently than read_excel? Try adding the argument parse_dates = ['dateBegin','dateEnd'] which will convert the strings in csvs to datetime objects.

Comment: Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For `pandas`, see [How to ask a good pandas question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: do you not understand the question ? @Evan

Comment: @JeffPernia In order for me or anyone to make a genuine attempt at helping you, you need to do the work of reading the three links I posted, creating a sample data frame for us to work with, posting the erroneous results or error message you're getting, and showing the results you'd like to get. For example, you're getting different results depending on how you read a file; how are we supposed to know what's in your files?